# Grabbing along normals

Tags: modeling

Alright, so you can do this with exturde, where you select along normals and pull the yellow thingy. is there a way to do that with (g) grab?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set your transform orientation to Normal:

[image]

Comment: double X will move along the local X axis, not the face normal X axis, even though it may be the same sometimes

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that, thanks!

Comment: Unless I'm wrong, you can only move along the normals if you switch to Normal Transform Orientations (your first paragraph)